# How to use the wanted version of OpenCV if there are more?

Tags: cmake

I have an application that uses OpenCV 2.4.9 and now I want to test OpenCV 3.0.0-beta. I have changed to the tag 3.0.0-beta and build the library. I have installed it and now I have 3 versions of OpenCV installed 2.4.8, 2.4.9 and 3.0.0-beta. Is there a way to choose the version I want?

The application is written in C++ and build using cmake. This is the part of code that makes the linking:

```
# ...
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    # ...
)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
# ...
```

Any help in choosing the version of OpenCV, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In find_package() command specify the version you need:

find_package(OpenCV 3.0.0 REQUIRED)

for example.

See the [CMake doc for find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) for more info.