How to use the desired opencv installation in c++?
I want to compile and run the following code that uses OpenCV in Ubuntu 22.04 using cmake.
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::string image_path = samples::findFile("starry_night.jpg");
    Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);

    if(img.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Could not read the image: " << image_path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    imshow("Display window", img);
    int k = waitKey(0);

    if(k == 's') {
        imwrite("output.png", img);
    }
    return 0;
}

The CMakeLists.txt is as the following
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(zooming)

add_executable(zooming main.cpp)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

target_link_libraries(zooming ${OpenCV_LIBS})

#install(TARGETS zooming RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

There are at least three installations of OpenCV in my system. One of them is installed by apt and the others are installed by compiling the source.
I compile the code by using cmake followed by make. After running the program, the following appears.
[ WARN:0] cv::samples::findFile('starry_night.jpg') => ''
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(3.4.10) /home/user/Softwares/OpenCV_3.4.10/opencv-opencv-25a1900/modules/core/src/utils/samples.cpp:62: error: (-2:Unspecified error) OpenCV samples: Can't find required data file: starry_night.jpg in function 'findFile'

I don't know where the above installation is set as default and how to change it.
UPDATE:
I want to use the 4.x version, but as shown above (in the output), the 3.4.10 is set as default. How can I change the default?
Please help me.

findFile docs: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/dba/group__core__utils__samples.html#ga3a33b00033b46c698ff6340d95569c13 -- run cout << cv::getBuildInformation() for more info on which OpenCV and which paths are involved

oh well OpenCV(3.4.10) /home/user/Softwares/OpenCV_3.4.10/opencv-opencv-25a1900/modules/core/src/utils/samples.cpp:62 already tells you which opencv you're dealing with. I would strongly recommend ditching 3.4. you should go with 4.x

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks. I want to use 4.x. But I don't know how to set it as default.

@ChristophRackwitz Now 3.x is set as default. But I don't know how!

You could probably use ccmake and adjust the opencv_dir in the UI

In find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED ) you can also specify the required version, but I don't know the syntax without googling

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378240/2393191

@Micka Thanks a lot. Now I can use OpenCV 4.5.4! Thanks again.
